# Meteor publication sorting

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor, meteor-publications

I have a Meteor-react app, what contains a collection, with a lots of data. I am displaying the data with **pagination**. 
At the server side I am just publishing the data for the current page.

So, I am publishing some data at the server side:

```
Meteor.publish('animals', function(currPage,displayPerPage, options) {
  const userId = this.userId;
  if (userId) {
    const currentUser = Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: userId });
    let skip = (currPage - 1) * displayPerPage;
    if (displayPerPage > 0) {
      Counts.publish(this, 'count-animals', Animals.find(
        {$and: [
          // Counter Query
        }
      ), {fastCount: true});

  return Animals.find(
     {$and: [
       // Data query
     ]}, {sort: options.sortOption, skip: skip, limit: displayPerPage });
     } else {
       Counts.publish(this, 'count-animals', 0);
       return [];
     }
  }
});
```

And on the client side I am using tracker:

```
export default AnimalsContainer = withTracker(({subscriptionName, subscriptionFun, options, counterName}) => {
  let displayPerPage = Session.get("displayPerPage");
  let currPage = Session.get("currPage");
  let paginationSub = Meteor.subscribe(subscriptionName, currPage, displayPerPage, options );
  let countAnimals = Counts.get(counterName);
  let data = Animals.find({}).fetch({});
  // console.log(data);
  return {
    // data: data,
    data: data.length <= displayPerPage ? data : data.slice(0, displayPerPage),
    countAnimals: countAnimals,
  }
})(Animals);
```

The problem is:

When I try to modify the sort options on the client side, the server sort not from the first data(Skippind the first some). Sometimes from the 20 th sometimes from the 10 th.
The type checks are done at both side.

Comment: Is `Counts.publish` relevant to your question?

Comment: It should not be relevat, because its just counting.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you're using sort + limit, having a different sorting can change drastically the published documents. If you want to sort only the document received by the client, you should do your sort client side and not server side.

Comment: Thank You for info, but I need to sort on the server side, and also have to limit it from server side, because faster performance. (Have more tousand object)
I tought sort should happen at first, and then limiting it. Shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Two things I can think of.

1. Keep on eye on the {sort: options.sortOption, skip: skip, limit: displayPerPage } order. As far as I know, it runs in the order you place it. So it sorts first, then skips, then limits.
2. Do sorts on both client and server. When the sort happens on the server and it's streamed to the client, the client holds a mini mongo version which doesn't guarantee an order. Therefore you need to sort the client as well.

Comment: Thank you,
1 - I know, thats the point. I want just publishing only **displayPerPage** number of document.
2 - I don't really understands why, but It was worked better. Not perfect, but sorted 95% precision. (There are some "D" between "W" and "Z", but works much better than before.  <br/>
What is confused me. Because the client should get only limited data.<br/>
May You have any opinion the left 5%? :D

Comment: So now sorted in the tracker also:
`let data = Animals.find({}, {sort: options.sortOption} ).fetch({});`

Comment: tested on different databases, and on both databases existed that "D" between "W" and "Z"